# Change forms in view function based on choices from MultipleChoiceFields (Django )

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have three forms alike Form1 containing MultipleChoiceFields, and BooleanFields with Buttons. In the views -function I want to change form from Form1 (form = Form1) to Form2 (form = Form2) and to Form3 from Form2 (Form3) respectively after fetching each MultipleChoicefield - choice from each field with cleaned_data. That is, the template has one and the same form but changes form/ form content after each form has been selected in three rounds. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
# in views.py
def function1(request,postID):
   # get id for objcet in class Label
   label = Label.objects.get(id=postID)
   template = template1.html

   if request.method == "POST":
     form = Form1(request.POST, prefix="form1")

     if form.is_valid and 'button' in request.POST:

          # Fetch chosen field in Form1 with cleaned_data
      a = form.cleaned_data['choices1']
      # get the dict with all of the choices in formfield "choices1" in
      # Form1 as keys
      choices_dict = dict(form.fields['choices1'].choices)
      # get the value for choice a in var a in choices_dict
      i = choices_dict.get(a)


      # Update the modelfield "labeled" in class Labeling in models.py
      # with the string/value for a in var i 
   Labeling.objects.filter(labeled="").update(labeled=i)
      # call function  post_one_label for posting and saving in db
      post_one_label(request, label)

     # change form from Form1 to Form2
     form = Form2(request.POST, prefix = "Form2")
     # validate the changed form after pressing button with name button in
     # the template
     if form.is_valid() and 'button' in request.POST:
         # Fetch chosen field in Form2, choices2 is MultipleChoiceField in Form2 alike choices1 in Form1,  with cleaned_data
         # call function  post_one_label for posting and saving in db
      post_one_label(request, label)

         # Problem; the form changes from Form1 to Form2 but after submitting  the cleaned_data for Form2  isn't processed, it returns None 
         #

         b = form.cleaned_data['choices2']


 else:
   form = Form1()
   # CSRF update
   c = {'form':form, 'label':label }
   c.update(csrf(request))
   # return RequestContext - request for template template1.html
   return render(request,template,c,context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def post_one_label(request, label):

   label = request.POST.get('label',"")
   oneLabel = Labeling(belongsTo=label, label=label)
   oneLabel.save()
```

in forms.py

```
class Form1(forms.Form):

   Button_A = forms.BooleanField(initial=False, required=False)
   Button_B = forms.BooleanField(initial=False, required=False) 





    choices_group1 = (('1','A'),
                 ('2','B'),
                 ('3','C'),

          )


    choices1 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=choices_group1,required=False)



    class Meta:
         model = Labeling # The class that I'm using, the same for all of the forms
         fields = ('choices1') # same as the field choices1 in the class Labeling

   # init and cleaned_data function   

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Form1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)



        def clean(self,*args, **kwargs):
            cleaned_data = super(Form1, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

            return cleaned_data


in template.html

    <form  action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{  form.as_p }}

         <input type="submit" name="button"  value="Submit"></input>

   </form>
```

Comment: I would consider using the [SessionWizardView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.SessionWizardView) which creates a flow (form1 -> form2 -> form3) but you can conditionally skip steps using the [condition_dict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.condition_dict)

Comment: thanks, I ended up using the SessionWizard as you suggested and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ian's recommendation I've used SessionWizard successfully. Here's a tutorial which is great if others runs into this as I did: [Video tutorial on Form Wizard (Sessionwizard) in Django](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSnBF-BmccQ)